# How to create trigger to post cuurent_timestamp on change of a table column or table data

Tags: mysql, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a table that has a status of either Approved, Rejected, or Pending. So I want to create a trigger that will populate the date_approved column on the table to current_timestamp when status is changed to approved. By default, status is pending.

What I've tried so far:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `date_approved_trig` ON CHANGE status = 'Approved' INSERT 
ON `transaction` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.date_approved = NOW();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I would really appreciate any help I could get